# Как убрать отступы у button и input?

Tags: html, css

Как убрать отступы между `.cart-nav1` и `.cart-nav2`, а также между элементами внутри `.search`?

[Верстка на сайте](http://p2.learning-verstka.esy.es/).
[Верстка в fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8hwq38v6/1/).

Код:

```css
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.header {
    background: #abeafa;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    padding-top: 24px;
}

.header .cart {
    clear: both;
    width: 270px;
    height: 150px;
    padding-top: 42px;
}
.header .cart .cart-nav {
    clear: both;
    background: #fb4d01;
}
.header .cart .cart-nav button.cart-nav1, .header .cart .cart-nav button.cart-nav2 {
    border: none;
    outline: medium none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    background: #ee4a02;
    width: 133px;
    height: 27px;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 11px;
    font-family:'Raleway', sans-serif;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.cart .cart-nav button.cart-nav2 {
    background: #e24602;
}
.cart .search input[type="search"] {
    width: 200px;
    height: 34px;
    border: none;
    outline: medium none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family:'Raleway', sans-serif;
    color: #0c0c0c;
    font-size: 10px;
}
.header .cart .search input[type="reset"] {
    background: url(http://p2.learning-verstka.esy.es/img/x.jpg) no-repeat 50% 50%;
    width: 34px;
    height: 34px;
    border: none;
    outline: medium none;
}
.header .cart .search .fa-search {
    width: 28px;
    height: 34px;
    background: #333333;
    color: #fff;
    line-height: 2;
}
```

```html
    <div class="header">
    <div class="cart cf">
        <div class="cart-nav cf">
            <button class="cart-nav1">view cart</button>
            <button class="cart-nav2">checkout</button>
        </div>
        <div class="search">
            <label>
                <input type="search" name="search" placeholder="search" />
                <input type="reset" value="" />
                <img class="fa fa-search" src="data:image/jpeg;base64, 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"/>
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Где я прописала их?

Comment: Непонятно, про какие именно отступы вы говорите. Там много что криво на первый взгляд. Приложите хотя бы скриншот и обведите это место, которое Вам не нравится

Comment: Алексей, вот скрин
http://prntscr.com/7h8uke

СПАСИБО!

Comment: Regent вот кусок кода.

Comment: Вот кусок кода
http://codepen.io/emelyanova/pen/yNogRy

Comment: С промежутком между VIEW CART и CHECKOUT отступ в 4px, потому что весь div у вас 270px, а каждая кнопка по 133. Итого 2 кнопки по 133 = 266.

Comment: То же самое с поиском: Всего 270, а все элементы дают 200 + 34 + 28 = 262 (остается 2 раза по 4px). Только я сейчас задумался, Вы хотите, чтобы этих отступов не было? В своём style.css Меняйте у cart-nav width с 133 на 135, и соответственно у search также (чтобы в сумме 270 было, например в fa-search с 28 на 35, в .search input[type="reset"] с 34 на 35)

Comment: @АлексейСаровский если просто у `.cart-nav1` и `.cart-nav2` поставить  ширину в 135px, то лично у меня вторая кнопка съезжает на новую строку. А вот если у кнопки `.cart-nav2` ещё добавить `float: right`, то кнопки располагаются на одной строке. Такая же история (`float: right`) при увеличении ширины элементов _200 + 34 + 28_.

Comment: @Regent хм... интересно, почему?

Comment: @АлексейСаровский а вот мне непонятно. Либо это где-то прописано в спецификации CSS, либо это тёмная магия.

Comment: ОГРОМНОЕ СПАСИБО!!!!!!

Comment: @АлексейСаровский, позвольте уточнить, в каком разделе спецификации начать искать ответ на этот...эээ... Фокус? Отступы? Флоаты?

Comment: @Polina достаточно набрать в Google запрос `css float`. Почему я предложил использовать `float` - потому что все другие попытки провались.

Comment: @metalurgus формулировка такая: _Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой ("почему этот код не работает?") должны включать желаемое поведение, конкретную проблему или ошибку и минимальный код для её воспроизведения прямо в вопросе._ Проблема и желаемое поведение указаны несколько вольготно, но всё же понятно о чем речь. Код не минимальный и неполный в плане HTML, но вечером, думаю, исправлю это - в фиддлe у меня есть _минимальный, полный, воспроизводимый пример_.

Comment: Уважаемый 
 
@metalurgus Пожалуйста, простите... Постараюсь писать максимально полно... Еще раз СПАСИБО! Огромная признательность всем, кто помогает. Я тут решила полностью переписать этот кусок. Т.к. меня перестал устраивать семантика и порядок блоков. Мне кажется, я безграмотно и бестолково их расположила.